# Angular transpiled files not being served on a Tomcat server through Java

Tags: java, angular, maven, tomcat

I've configured my Tomcat server to run through IntelliJ Ultimate Edition. Using the Maven webapp archetype it will serve the default index page fine. I wrote my webpages in Angular and transpiled them into .js files which are located within my wepapp folder. When I run the server it loads the blank html page and gives me a "failed to load resource: server responded with a status of 404 ()" for each of the .js files.

It should be loading a "login" page with some basic CSS and fields for username and password. Instead I get a blank page and a lot of 404 errors.

Comment: check if you can hover on the html page and access the js files ? if not then set the <base href='/'> accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we just had to run ng build --aot whenever we transpiled the files and now it runs.